Is working for trading company that gives interest to user Haram?
I’ve recently started working at a trading company as a software engineer, there business model is as follows:
Their main source of profit is trading fees.
But, they give their customers interest on their money, basically the company transfer all users money to the central bank, they gain interest on that money, then they give the interest to end customers.
Is working for such company Haram or Halal?
My actual work has nothing to do with interst.

yup it is haram brother, I'm talking from experience since I was in a similar situation, when I searched I found out that not only riba is haram, but also contributing to riba is haram even indirectly, because as a company there is no specific individual who is giving the interests so that all the blame falls on him, no it's a team effort and a lot of people are contributing to that phenomenon (which is riba), so calculating that interest is haram, building the software solution that will give people access to that interest is haram, mopping the floors where all that is happening is haram, and the list goes on ... you get the point
Of course if one doesn't know, he is not guilty, but once one knows the activity is haram, and somehow he is contributing to that eco-system leading to haram, he should start searching for an alternative. May Allah help you find a better place.
